# Why does unbound pass dohclient test but fails 404 with curl and firefox?

Tags: domain-name-system, unbound

I have built a DoH resolver with unbound and my simple configuration tests correctly:

`unbound-checkconf: no errors in /unbound/unbound.conf`

My next test is to use the included dohclient:

`dohclient -s 10.10.10.10 cnn.com AAAA IN`

```
Request headers
:method: GET
:path: /dns-query?dns=AAABAAABAAAAAAABhswwyy2hbn0AABwAAQAAKRAAAACAAAAA
:scheme: https
:authority: 10.10.10.10
content-type: application/dns-message
:status 200
content-type application/dns-message
content-length 260
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, rcode: NOERROR, id: 0
;; flags: qr rd ra ; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 8, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1 
;; QUESTION SECTION:
cnn.com.        IN      AAAA

;; ANSWER SECTION:
cnn.com.        300     IN      AAAA    2a04:4e42:a00::773

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0; flags: do ; udp: 1232
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 260
```

So ... it appears that things are working properly.

But then I try a similar test with curl:

`curl --doh-url https://doh.mydomain.com cnn.com`

and I get:

`curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host name`

... and in the unbound logs I see:

`debug: http2 request invalid, returning :status=404`

If I attempt to hit the unbound server with firefox, it fails and the unbound log shows me:

`debug: http2 request invalid, returning :status=404`

My ```curl --version`` shows me that:

`Features: alt-svc AsynchDNS GSS-API HSTS HTTP2 HTTPS-proxy IPv6 Kerberos Largefile libz NTLM NTLM_WB SPNEGO SSL TLS-SRP UnixSockets`

... so I do support http2 and my firefox is brand new updated from last night.

Here is the verbose output from the failed curl command:

```
* We are completely uploaded and fine
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / AEAD-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=mydomain.com
*  start date: Nov 24 00:00:00 2023 GMT
*  expire date: Feb 22 23:59:59 2024 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "doh.mydomain.com" matched cert's "*.mydomain.com"
*  issuer: C=AT; O=ZeroSSL; CN=ZeroSSL ECC Domain Secure Site CA
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multiplexing
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x13980cc00)
> POST / HTTP/2
Host: doh.mydomain.com
accept: */*
content-type: application/dns-message
content-length: 25

* We are completely uploaded and fine
< HTTP/2 404 
< 
* Connection #1 to host doh.mydomain.com left intact
* a DoH request is completed, 1 to go
< HTTP/2 404 
< 
* Connection #2 to host doh.mydomain.com left intact
* a DoH request is completed, 0 to go
* DoH: Too small type A for cnn.com
* DoH: Too small type AAAA for cnn.com
* Closing connection 0
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host name
```

Why is curl failing with a 404 ?

Why does dohclient succeed and these "normal" clients (curl and firefox) fail ?

Comment: For curl try the path specified in the doc: `--doh-url https://doh.mydomain.com/dns-query` . For Firefox I don't know; how/where did you configure it?

Comment: Wow - I'll be damned!  adding /dns-query to the end of the address caused the curl command to complete successfully!  It also caused firefox to begin to work.  I was simply entering an address (doh.mydomain.com) into the firefox DNS-Over-HTTPS dialog ... but adding the /dns-query caused it to begin to work.  Thank you!

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 please add your comment as the asnwer so that the OP can accept it and the question will be considered closed and resolved.

Answer (score 1):

As [the documentation says](https://unbound.docs.nlnetlabs.nl/en/latest/topics/privacy/dns-over-https.html#implementation-details) unbound returns 404 if you don't specify the correct path, which defaults to `/dns-query` and you presumably didn't change. The `dohclient` output shows it uses this path -- and your `curl` output shows it only did `POST /` because that's what you specified and `curl` handles *any* URL. Although you didn't show the Firefox config, it presumably has the same flexibility.